# Cannot send notification to Google Assistant (Target intent is not a valid updatable intent.)

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I've successfully implemented notifications for Google Assistant when it was in Developer Preview, but after this feature was released they stopped working.

```
    jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
        let db = fbApp.database("https://[REDACTED].firebaseio.com/").ref();
        //...
        if (uid == undefined) {
            res.status(404).send("Not found");
            return
        }
        console.log(`Sending notification to ${uid}`)
        let notif = {
            userNotification: {
                title: "this is test intent"
            },
            target: {
                userId: uid,
                intent: 'get_location'
            }
        }
        requestLib.post('https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send', {
          'auth': {
            'bearer': tokens.access_token
          },
          'json': true,
          'body': { 'customPushMessage': notif, 'isInSandbox': true }
        }, function(err,httpResponse,body) {
          console.log(body);
          res.status(httpResponse.statusCode).send(httpResponse.statusMessage);
        });
    });
```

Response is 400: Bad request with following body

```
{ error: 
   { code: 400,
     message: 'Target intent get_location is not a valid updatable intent. Please check that the intent has been configured for updates.',
     status: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' } }
```

I'm using Dialogflow for intents and can't find where to make "valid updatable intent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that intent that is triggered by notification MUST be added to implicit invocation.
To do it, go to Dialogflow console, Main menu -> Integrations -> Google Assistant integration settings and add your intent (get_location in my case) to implicit invocations.
This solved the issue

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if the issue is now solved, so that the community sees that this question is solved. Thanks!